# Does turning the flags to gold unlock anything?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

In Super Mario 3D Land if you land right on the top of the flag pole (so that Mario does a sort of one-handed handstand), you get a 1-up. I also noticed that the Mario flag that goes up is gold instead of red.

Does it unlock anything if you get all gold flags in a world/the whole game? Or is it just a nice aesthetic change from red because you got a 1-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting them all is one of [5 things you can do](http://www.ign.com/cheats/games/super-mario-3d-land-3ds-99437) to get a "star" on your save file in the main menu.  The others are:

> Defeat Bowser in World 8's last level, successfully complete all levels with Mario,  successfully complete all levels with Luigi, and  collect all star coins.

Comment: Does unlocking all 5 do anything?

Comment: Nothing special, really.  Although rumor has it there's a way to make the stars *shiny* by completing an even *harder* challenge...

Comment: @AshleyNunn, it turns out I was wrong!  Getting all 5 gold stars unlocks a secret Final Level.